# не работают звуковые драйвера Asus TUF gaming fx506heb

Tags: аудио, драйвер

Помогите решить проблему:
В общем, я однажды решил переустановить драйвера на звук от realtek на ноутбуке, но после удаления появилась следующая проблема:
Звук отказывается работать при любых драйверах, ставил скачанные из интернета, возвращал стандартные, искал по модели материнской платы - всё не работало, даже после обновления винды, когда установились стандартные, звук не работал.
При этом без драйверов звук работает, но как-то надоедает их постоянно удалять, да и настроек не хватает. К тому же просто удаление через диспетчер устройств не помогает, удаляю с помощью установщика других драйверов, а после отменяю установку.

Windows 11 лицензионный, ноутбук Asus TUF gaming fx506heb

Comment: Одну проблему можно решить запретом [автообновления драйверов](https://pureinfotech.com/disable-automatic-driver-install-windows-11/).

Comment: Спасибо, но это на крайний случай, если решение без ампутации не найдётся совсем.